# How to handle errors with curl_multi

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

i've been trying to handle errors for curl_multi but it seems it's not working proper. I think i'm doing something wrong.
Thnx in advance!
Here is my code:

```
// array of curl handles
$multiCurl = array();
// data to be returned
$result = array();
// multi handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$urls=array(
 "1" => ''.$ip_stand.'/rentsystem/ch'.$loc.'.php',
 "2" => ''.$ip_stand.'/rentsystem/sensor'.$loc.'.php'
);
foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {

  // URL from which data will be fetched

  $multiCurl[$i] = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
  curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($multiCurl[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $multiCurl[$i]);
 
}
$index=null;
do {
  $status=curl_multi_exec($mh,$index);
   echo "ERROR!\n " . curl_multi_strerror($status);
} while($index > 0);
 
//$curl_error = curl_multi_error($mh);
// get content and remove handles
foreach($multiCurl as $k => $ch) {
  $result[$k] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
  
  curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
}
```